# UWP - Onscreen keyboard closes when switching to another textbox

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm experiencing a strange bug(?) with my uwp app.

I have a page with multiple textboxes for user input that each have the `InputScope` set to number, which then opens the keyboard in tablet mode as expected. However if you tap on the next box the keyboard closes and a second tap is needed to open the keyboard. This also happens if the user hits tab to switch boxes.

I presume this has something to do with the `Focus()` event firing before the previous textbox has fired the loss of focus event but im unsure how to override the behavior.

How can i prevent the onscreen keyboard from closing, but also make sure the correct inputscope is still maintained?

Edit: Upon further investigation, the issue seems to be almost random. Sometimes you can move to different boxes and it remains open but other times it closes the keyboard every time.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm still experiencing issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been resolved with some others, in Windows 10 version 1803 released on 30th April, 2018.

Comment: This. I've had this same problem for a while now and updating Windows to the most recent (at the time of writing) version has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to play with InputPane that is a container for on-screen keyboard. For example, doing a small delay once the pane is trying to hide, then detect attempts to show the pane again (and cancel pending hide).

```
    myPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
    myPane.Showing += myShowingHandler();
    myPane.Hiding += myHidingHandler();
```

At least, you can receive a size of underlying screen region on the pane showing so you can put a placeholder (margin or dummy grid) on your UI to prevent it jumping up and down on keyboard show/hide.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not worried about the ui jumping around, I need the keyboard to remain open when it is meant to stay open.

Comment: @Takarii, quick question: what is "IsTabStop" property value for your text boxes? especially that ones who do not show the keyboard? Another option is to call myPane.TryShow() inside myHidingHandler(). Do you see the effect?

Comment: All boxes are exactly the same. The issue only presents itself when selecting another text box directly after one another. If i tap anywhere else, such as another control or whitespace then the next textbox to be selected opens the keyboard as expected. I tried changing tabstop to false and that meant the keyboard never opened. I looked up the event order and the focus event fires on the new control before the lostfocus event fires on the old one. So i think that my solution needs to look at preventing the keyboard closing if the old focus is a textbox as well as the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your case on my WP but I cannot reproduce your experience:
[image: KeyboardWorking]

When I tap to other TextBox, keyboard stays opened and I can continue typing.
Keyboard hides as expected when I tap somewhere to whitespace.

Don't you have keyboard connected to your device?

Comment: its possible this issue im experiencing isnt present in the windows phone version and may be specific to tablet mode.

Comment: No, there is no keyboard attached. The device is a tablet

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you, but I experience similar missbehaviour on my Windows tablet PC as well. Keyboard hides when switching to other textbox and vice-versa. Also when typing, some pressed keystrokes do insert character into TextBox. There're several settings in "Typing", but non of them seems to have impact on behaviour in UWP app. Last thing remains to file a bug to MS.